# Run time Exception- unable to start receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

When I used a Toast message, it was working. Now when I replaced it with alert dialog, I'm getting Run Time Exception. Here is my code:

```
public class ConnectionReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
//          Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Connection is Active",
//                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            AlertDialog successAlert=new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            successAlert.setMessage("Internet Connection is Active");
            successAlert.show();

        } else {
              AlertDialog failureAlert=new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
              failureAlert.setMessage("Internet Connection Timed Out....Please try again");
              failureAlert.show();
        }

    }
}
```

It was displaying toast messages properly. Now when I added alert dialog, my app is crashing . Can't figure out the reason. Is anything wrong in the alert dialog?

Log Cat Entries:

```
06-11 06:02:02.010: W/dalvikvm(3823): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2abbba8)
06-11 06:02:02.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3823): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 06:02:02.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3823): Process: com.example.finalassignment, PID: 3823
06-11 06:02:02.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3823): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.finalassignment.ConnectionReciever: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
06-11 06:02:02.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3823):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2426)
06-11 06:02:02.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3823):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-11 06:02:02.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3823):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
06-11 06:02:02.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3823):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-11 06:02:02.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3823):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-11 06:02:02.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3823):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-11 06:02:02.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3823):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 06:02:02.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3823):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-11 06:02:02.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3823):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-11 06:02:02.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3823):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-11 06:02:02.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3823):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-11 06:02:02.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3823): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
06-11 06:02:02.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3823):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:540)
06-11 06:02:02.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3823):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
06-11 06:02:02.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3823):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
06-11 06:02:02.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3823):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
06-11 06:02:02.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3823):     at com.example.finalassignment.ConnectionReciever.onReceive(ConnectionReciever.java:25)
06-11 06:02:02.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3823):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2419)
```

Comment: With Application context you cant show dialog..you need to pass Activity Context to show dialog..

Comment: i used to context, which is passed from activity

Comment: I passed activity context like this: Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConnectionReciever.class);
  sendBroadcast(intent);

Comment: here u are using context which is received in onReceive method which is not Activity Context which is application context.For this you need to take receiver as a inner class and show dialog

Comment: You mean i should write broadcast receiver inside the activity?

Comment: yes..then you have populate dialog with Activity reference

Comment: So whatever i wrote in a separate class i nned to write it inside activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is with activity context. you need to pass context of activity to show dialog.

Comment: I passed activity context like this: Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConnectionReciever.class); sendBroadcast(intent);

Comment: The problem is you are trying to show an AlertDialog from a BroadcastReceiver, which isn't allowed. You can't show an AlertDialog from a BroadcastReceiver. Only activities can display dialogs.

You should do something else, have the BroadcastReceiver start on boot as you do and start an activity to show the dialog.

Comment: I'll be checking whether internet connection is active or not inside broadcast receiver...Then how i can display alert in activity?

Comment: Step 1: Create a broadcast receiver in your activity from where you are starting your service. Code:BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("create_dialog")) {
                // create your dialog here.
            }
        } ;                                                                   Step 2: Register your receiver after creating your broadcast receiver.   IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("create_dialog");
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

Comment: You mean i should write the broadcast receiver inside the activity as a inner class?

Comment: please follow all the above steps to show dialog while using broadcast.

Comment: But this is for registering dynamically..I have registered my receiver in the manifest

Comment: it is bad to add alert dialog in onRecieve method..there is another method also... YOu should call new activity and add theme as a dialog theme to that activity in manifest file

Comment: @user1458027 I created 2 methods in the activity 
..And then called thoe methods from the broadcastreciever..I made broadcastreciever as a inner class in the activity

Comment: Now its not crashing but its not giving any dialog

Comment: Have you applied your activity theme as dialog in manifest file ??

Answer (score 1):

The `Context` passed on as argument to `onReceive()` is-a `ReceiverRestrictedContext`.

To show dialogs, you need a `Context` that is-a `Activity`.

To show a notification from a broadcast receiver, use a `Notification` and not a dialog.

If you have a receiver registered in the manifest, do not attempt to pass in an `Activity` reference to it. The system is free to kill your process once `onReceive()` returns - you cannot do anything asynchronous (such as `Dialog`s) there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it may happen if you add the popupo window or dialog when the parent view is not ready to show up yet and the view has not been attached to the window yet.

The solution is to check if the view is attached to the window before triggering the popup/dialog or delay the popup for a few hundred milliseconds.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

Occurs when the OS is unable to decide to which activity should it relate the window called, Alert dialog in this case. Now here you are trying to use the context passed from the Broad cast reciever, which still will not indicate exactly which activity should the alert dialog box be attached to. instead, use `MyActivity.this` as the context in the Alert Dialog and everything will work fine.

Modify the code as:

```
public class ConnectionReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
 //          Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Connection is Active",
 //                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
        // Replace MyActivity with your activity name in MyActivity.this
        alertDialog.setMessage("Internet Connection is Active");
        alertDialog.show();

    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyProfile.this);
        // Replace MyActivity with your activity name in MyActivity.this
        alertDialog.setMessage("Internet Connection Timed Out....Please try again");
        alertDialog.show();

    }

}
}
```

Comment: I'm getting no enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope;

Comment: Oh it's way to long to explain that. Actually you need to create an activity instance in your class. can you send accross ur mail id for chat?